# When can a Gaussian surface need not to be closed?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

Consider two charges, one $+q$ at $(0,0,r_+)$, the other $-q$ at $(0,0,r_-)$, both $r_-,r_+>0$. Calculate the flux through the plane $x-y$ - it is zero. Just like the flux through any closed surface that contains the two charges, as given by Gauss's law.

Of course, if one charge was on the other side of the plane, the result (flux through plan) would not be in accordance with Gauss's law, but will agree with it qualitatively - it will be zero only if the total charge on one side equals that on the other one.

So it seems plausible to ask - under what conditions can an open surface be used as a Gaussian surface in general? And in particular if the only information I want is to detect a surplus of charge on one side?

Comment: Are you saying the two charges are located on the z-axis equally spaced from the x-y plane?

Comment: @Farcher The net flux is zero, due to the flux of each charge being independent of charge's position.

Comment: @proton I assume this is because the area of the xy plane is infinite so all of the “bottom” half of the field lines from each of the charges pass through that plane?

Comment: @Farcher You are corrrect.